# Can a "because" clause, or any clause, be the subject of a sentence?

Tags: parsing

> **(Just) because I am free** doesn't mean I want to do homework.

I made this sentence and it sound right to me; adding “just” makes me feel more certain. However, I can't parse it. I thought "Because I am free" cannot be the subject because it is a clause.

Comment: Why not? Clauses can freely function as subject, as in "To turn back now would be a mistake". But that's irrelevant here since the expression "(Just) because I am free" is not a clause but a preposition phrase with "because" as head and the clause "I am free" as its complement.

Comment: @BillJ "(Just) because I am free" is a preposition phrase？ I thought a preposition phrase is something like "because of my availability" "In this room", and such a structure can't be the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just demonstrated that, indeed, a *because* clause can be the subject of a sentence.

If somebody somewhere has a grammar of English that doesn't allow this, then their grammar is of something that isn't English (or, at least, isn't your English or my English).